# The PHP executes the shell_exec command but doesn't do anything

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, curl

I'm using this script to post some date using curl in a post.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

var1=`base64 javascript_100.file`

# post it 3 times
for i in `seq 1 3`; do

/usr/bin/curl -i --verbose -d "jobTexterea=$var1" http://my_server_address/target_page.php

done
```

I don't have any problems executing the post.sh file using my Shell however when i invoke it inside my php script using `shell_exec('sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh')` I'm getting this error from my `var_dump(shell_exec('sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh'));`.

> Error: () HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Sat, 24 Sep 2016 15:14:38 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2h-fips PHP/5.6.25 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25 Location: http://my_server_ ddress/ Content-Length: 401 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 A MySQL error has occurred.
>   Your Query: INSERT INTO jobsNum_pro_batch (`job_batch_id` , `jobs_in_batch` , `job_type` ) VALUES ( '26' ,'1' ,'JavaScript' )

The code in the **post.sh** file posts the information to the **target_page.php** wich puts all the content into different tables in a database. The thing is that no information is being uploaded into the database with running `shell_exec('sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh')` from a PHP page. However, the command itself runs without errors, I checked it with

```
<?php
    if (shell_exec('sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh')){ 
        echo "<b> shell_exec was executed </b><br>";
        var_dump(shell_exec('sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh'));
    } else {
        echo "<b> shell_exec was not executed </b><br>";
    }
?>
```

I'm getting the message **shell_exec was executed**

Has anyone an idea what went wrong?

Comment: There is a relative filepath in your script. Are you running it from the same directory in both cases?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The PHP script that executing the shell_exec is in a different folder than the **post.sh** file. I use the full path /var/....../post.sh of the file in the shell_exec command.

Comment: not sure but in that case would the file `javascript_100.file` would be accessible from a different directory?

Comment: The `javascript_100.file`is in the same folder as the `post.sh` file so there are not supposed to be any complications. I can execute the `post.sh` file from the shell itself and everything would work as it should.

Comment: you mean this works? `cd /tmp; sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh` ?

Comment: if you mean inside the shell_exec so this `shell_exec(cd /tmp; sh /path_to_post_file/post.sh);` doesn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why did you delete your answer? I had to do a small change there and it worked, I wanted to post it there as a comment.

Comment: I deleted it because it wasn't answering the question: I was 99% sure this was the problem and it isn't. I haven't enough info to continue.

Comment: I'll post your answer with my change as a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick! Thanks to @Jean-FrançoisFabre and a small change to his code and problem is gone!

```
#!/bin/sh

progdir=$(dirname $0)

var1=`base64 $progdir/javascript_100.file`

# post it 3 times
for i in `seq 1 3`; do

/usr/bin/curl -i --verbose -d "jobTexterea=$var1" http://my_server_address/target_page.php

done
```